# Work_dim in NDRange

Tags: opencl

I can not understand what work_dim is for in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()?

So, what is the difference between work_dim=1 and work_dim=2?
And why work items are grouped into work groups?
A work item or a work group is a thread running on the device (or neither)?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`work_dim` is the **number of dimensions** for the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` execution.

If you specify `work_dim = 1`, then the **global** and **local work sizes** are **unidimensional**. Thus, inside the kernels you can only access info in the **first dimension**, e.g. `get_global_id(0)`, etc.

If you specify `work_dim = 2` or `3`, then you must also specify **2** or **3 dimensional global** and **local worksizes**; in such case, you can access info inside the kernels in **2** or **3 dimensions**, e.g. `get_global_id(1)`, or `get_group_id(2)`.

In practice you can do everything in **1D**, but for dealing with **2D** or **3D** data, it maybe simpler to directly use **2/3 dimensional kernels**; for example, in the case of **2D** data, such as an image, if each thread/work-item is to deal with a single pixel, each thread/work-item could deal with the pixel at coordinates `(x,y)`, with `x = get_global_id(0)` and `y = get_global_id(1)`.

A **work-item** is a **thread**, while **work-groups** are **groups of work-items/threads**.

I believe the division work-groups / work-items is related with the hardware architecture of GPUs and other accelerators (e.g. Cell/BE); you can map the execution of work-groups to GPU Stream Multiprocessors (in NVIDIA talk) or SPUs (in IBM/Cell talk), while the corresponding work-itens would run inside the execution units of the Stream MultiProcessors and/or SPUs. It's not uncommon to have `work group size = 1` if you are executing kernels in a CPU (e.g. for a quad-core, you would have 4 work groups, each one with one work item - though in my experience it's usually better to have more workgroups than CPU cores).

Check the [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) reference manual, as well as the OpenCl manual for whichever device your are programming. The [quick reference card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-1-quick-reference-card.pdf) is also very helpful.