# Is it valid to have differing dimensions with cl::NDRange for enqueueing a kernel?

Tags: opencl

If for example the global dimensions are `cl::NDRange{1024x1024}`, is it valid to have a local dimension of `cl::NDRange{32}` ?

The program certainly runs if the dimensions are provided by that, but maybe the work dim is set to something else silently?

What happens if differing sizes are given?

The [official specs](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/pdf/OpenCL_API.pdf) write that:

> Each work-item is assigned to a work-group and given a local ID to represent its position within the
> work-group. A work-item’s local ID is an N-dimensional tuple with components in the range from
> zero to the size of the work-group in that dimension minus one.

I don't see differing dimensions as explicitly forbidden, despite [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179471/work-dim-in-ndrange) stating otherwise.

Comment: I believe your local dimensions need to divide your global dimensions. So if you're using 2 dimensions globally (1024, 1024) then you can have locally (32, 1)  but they are set with a different array argument. See https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957125/questions-about-global-and-local-work-size. Sorry but I don't know if the c++ API is different, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global range has to be a multiple of local range component-wise. `1024*1024` global is ok for `32*1` local, as `1024` (x) is a multiple of `32` and `1024` (y) is a multiple of `1`.
For best cross-vendor compatibility, local range itself should be 64 threads or a multiple of 64 threads, so for example `64*1`, `32*2`, or `8*8`. Local range 32 is fine on Nvidia GPUs, but will keep half of ALUs idle on AMD GPUs.

The choice of local range aspect ratio (`64*1`/`32*2`/`8*8`) is generally a free performance tuning parameter, except when you explicitely use `local` memory in the kernel. It's important for global memory coalescence (`64*1` is ideal here) and for branching (`8*8` is ideal in cases where different 2D image regions follow different branches in the kernel).